# psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type integer to interval

Tags: django, django-models

Error when running migrations.AlterField in a conversion from IntegerField to DurationField using PosgreSQL with Django 2.2. Any workaround?

Comment: What's the error, and how are you handling the change of type? Is it a mandatory field? Most likely this should be a multi-stage migration. Please show the before and after field def and the migration code.

Comment: Also, what is the actual error - this would be useful too!